# Problem when Using Threads to update Javafx ProgressBar in multiple Ocassions

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am using java 8 (amazon correto).
I am using JavaFX with the help of Scenebuilder for the project.
My application is in Main.java, and the current functionality is implemented in Controller.java

Currently, I aim to create a progress bar `@FXML private ProgressBar prog;`.
As soon as my GUI app loads I want the progress bar to slowly update till it reaches 50% from 0%.
Then after the user clicks a button I want to update the rest of the progress bar from 50% to 100%.

I made my controller implement initilizable so that I can update the bar from 0 to 50%.
This the java Task I defined to use to do that.

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

public class updateBar extends Task<Void> {
     final double max_bar = 1000;
     private double start;
     private double max;
     private ProgressBar prog;

     public updateBar(double start, double max, ProgressBar prog) {
         this.start = start;
         this.max = max;
         this.prog  = prog;
     }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
         for (double i = this.start; i <= this.max; i++) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            prog.setProgress(i/max_bar);
            System.out.println(prog.getProgress());
            System.out.println(i+"\t"+this.max);
//            updateProgress(i, max_bar);
        }
         return null;
    }
}
```

My initialize method looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Thread first =  new Thread((progressB(1,(double)max_bar/2)));
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        pool.execute(first);

    }
```

The problem comes here, the initial update of the progress bar works fine but the second time I want to update it doesn't work (This is the onsubmit event).

This the onsubmit event:

```
    public void onSubmit() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread last = new Thread((progressB(max_bar/2,max_bar)));
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        pool.execute(last);
        while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
        }
        //  method below works
        Platform.runLater(this::newWin);
    }
```

When I call onsubmit the thread doesn't start and the whole GUI app freezes.

**I also tried**

```
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {

    @Override public Void call() {
        final int max = 1000;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max/2; i++) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
        }
    };


    Task lst = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        final int max = 1000;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            updateProgress(i, max);
        }
        return null;
        }
    };

    public void onSubmit() throws InterruptedException {
        prog.progressProperty().bind(progressB(max_bar/2,max_bar).progressProperty());
        prog.progressProperty().bind(lst.progressProperty());
        Thread last = new Thread(lst);
        last.start();
        last.join();

        //  method below works
        Platform.runLater(this::newWin);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
       prog.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
       new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

What am I missing? The progress bar won't update properly for all the above techniques I have used.

Comment: In your first block of code you're updating the UI from a background thread. Never do that. In your next examples you're using `updateProgress`, which is good, and it _appears_ you're binding the progress of the bar to the task. However, it's not clear to me if you're actually binding to the correct _instance_ of your `Task` implementation. It would be good to provide a [mre]. That all being said, if all you want to do is change the progress over time then using threads is overkill and unnecessarily complicated. Just use the animation API (e.g. `javafx.animation.Timeline`).